# Purpose of dbo.Policies table in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver

What is the purpose of the `[dbo].][Policies]` table in SSRS **ReportServerDB** database?

I see two columns, `PolicyID` and `PolicyFlag` and I don't get any clue about purpose of this table. Is it possible to add anew row into that table and what represents those data, i.e. rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row of `Policies` table declares via `PolicyFlag` column if that policy is defined for system roles.

A policy can be related only with created user defined objects, `UserType = 1` in `User` table. System defined objects like `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` and Local Server Administrator aren't mapped with policies.

If you run this query:

```
SELECT b.username, 
       c.policyflag, 
       d.rolename, 
       b.usertype, 
       c.policyid 
FROM   policyuserrole a 
       INNER JOIN users b 
               ON a.userid = b.userid 
       INNER JOIN policies c 
               ON a.policyid = c.policyid 
       INNER JOIN roles d 
               ON a.roleid = d.roleid
```

[image]

By default you will have two rows in Policies table.

[REFERENCE](http://sornanara.blogspot.com.co/2011/07/ssrs-reportserver-database-tables_10.html)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Worth noting that, even after knowing this info (the relationship between these 3 tables), you still cannot manually add user-role mappings via TSQL, even if you get the SID's correct. You must do it via Report Manager. :\